# Why is the output of this code 2 instead of 8?

Tags: arrays, c, memory, printing

```c
int main()
{
    int array[5];
    int *p,*q;
    p =&array[1];
    q=&array[3];
    printf("%d\n",q);
    printf("%d\n",p);
    printf("%d",q-p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: The Code in Question]

The memory of `p` and `q` are printed out too, but why is the difference 2 instead of 8?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text directly.

Comment: Subtracting pointers is the same as subtracting **indexes**. `3-1=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking **pointer arithmetic**.  When you have two pointers to elements in the same array, subtracting those pointers gives you the difference in bytes between the addresses **divided by** the byte size of the *dereferenced pointer type*.  So, the result of subtracting two pointers is the number of **elements** between their addresses, not the number of **bytes**, as you are expecting.

So, in your case, you are subtracting `int*` pointers, and `sizeof(int)` is clearly 4 bytes in your compiler, so there are 8 bytes between the addresses of `&array[1]` and `&array[3]`, which is 2 `int` elements between `array[1]` and `array[3]`.

```
---------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
---------------------
    ^       ^
    p       q

p = 0xBE460A94
q = 0xBE460A9C
```

Try this instead, and you will see 8 instead:

```c
int main()
{
    int array[5];
    char *p, *q;
    p = (char*) &array[1];
    q = (char*) &array[3];
    printf("%p\n", q);
    printf("%p\n", p);
    printf("%d", q - p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Same addresses, but different pointer types, so different result.